# php if return == false echo something

Tags: php

I'm using a include file to translate my text. it works pretty good, but now I need to on button click translate some mor words, and return doesn't work anymore, but echo does.

so what I'm searching is a way of know if return is possible or not, code example

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($palavras); $i++) {
    if ($palavras[$i] == $palavra) {
        if($lingua == 1) {
            return $traducao_1[$i];
        }
        if($lingua == 2) {
            return $traducao_2[$i];
        }
    }
}
```

this one works good first time page is executed, since this is included file.

how to make this?

```
if(!return $traducao_1[$i]) {
```

thanks

ok, tryed to answer, but always got an error, so I'm editing this as answer

Thank you all for help, I manage a way of make it work like adding one action to the function and checking if action == , then do something, like this

```
function test($palavra, $lingua, $accao) {
for ($i = 0; $i < count($palavras); $i++) {
    if ($palavras[$i] == $palavra) {
        if($lingua == 1) {
            if($accao != "2_chamada") {
                return $traducao_1[$i];
            } else {
                echo $traducao_1[$i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Again, thanks for help

Comment: The `return` statement immediately returns to the caller and doesn't return a value to the function in which it was executed, you can't use it in a conditional.

Answer (score 0):

maybe check to see if it's set first before returning

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($palavras); $i++) {
    if ($palavras[$i] == $palavra) {
        if($lingua == 1) {
            $return = $traducao_1[$i];
            if($return != false) {
                return $return;
            } else {
                echo 'something';
            }
        }
        if($lingua == 2) {
            $return = $traducao_2[$i];
            if($return != '') {
                return $return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

return can only be used in functions

i reccommend this for you

```
function test($palavras,$palavra,$traducao_1,$traducao_2){
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($palavras); $i++) {
        if ($palavras[$i] == $palavra) {
            if($lingua == 1) {
                return $traducao_1[$i];
            }
            if($lingua == 2) {
                return $traducao_2[$i];
            }
        }
    }
}


if(!test($palavras)) {
```